# How to add an array of classes to a div?

Tags: css

I have a website and I should make certain divs transparent. I don't want to duplicate my divs with a transparent tag. I want to archieve something like this.

```
.wrapper { --div properties-- }
.transparent { --transparency properties --}
```

I want to set class attributes like this.

```
<div class="wrapper . transparent"></div>
```

So this div would get all the properties from wrapper style, then apply a transparent background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [class selectors](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssintermediate/classid/) instead of ID selectors:

```
.wrapper { --div properties-- }
.transparent { --transparency properties --}
```

And separate your class names by a single space in your HTML markup:

```
<div class="wrapper transparent"></div>
```

Comment: It's the space seperates selectors?

Comment: @AnılÜnal The space separates the classes being referenced in the `class` attribute.